# Как получить маршруты общественного транспорта, проходящие через точку?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

В запрос построения маршрутов передаются минимум две точки, а мне нужно указать одну точку и вывести маршруты общественного транспорта, которые через нее проходят. Не нашел как такое сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Узнать маршруты общественного транспорта в точке через API Яндекс.Карт нельзя, можно только строить маршрут по двум точкам, как Вы и написали.